# Can I still create gitlab project after I ran git commit for a new project?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am writing a new codebase. The plan was that this codebase will be a new project at our gitlab group. What I should have done is to create this new gitlab project at gitlab first, and then at my local directory to run those git commands (git add, git commit and git push).

But I forgot about that plan, I first ran git add and git commit. When fit push failed with the following message:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

I realized I do not create project yet.

What should I do now? Can I still go to gitlab to create the project?

Comment: `git remote add origin <url>`

Comment: I do not think this will work since I do not create the project yet, so there is no <url>, right?

Comment: Git is a *decentralized* VCS so it does not matter to your local repo if and where other repos exist. Just create it and add as origin as per @jojo2357's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a git repo on gitlab, then run in your project

`git remote add origin <url>`

You may need to do more before pushing, but listen to git's complaints, they are typically helpful